# Hosted email provider similar to Gmail

Tags: email, hosting, webmail

I am using Google's hosted email for my business right now.  I like the gmail/web interface but I need to create some account aliases, auto-responders, etc.

It is also $50/yr per account which I can't justify on spending for a simple alias or forwarder.

Hosted exchange would work, but I would like a web UI that is lighter weight or more performant.

Comment: Google Apps does have a free tier if you'd need the features that the business level affords: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create aliases in Google Apps without needing a new account.  There are a couple of methods for this.

1) In the control panel, go to "Organisation and Users" then select the user you want to send the email to.  Select "Add nickname" from the nicknames section.  Add the alias ("sales" etc.) and it will point to that user and go into their inbox.

2) For aliases to multiple users, just create a group.  You can use this to forward to accounts outside of your domain, and a group can consist of only one user, so this is actually a better method if you want to be able to view all of your aliases in one place.

Your auto-responders are trickier.  Simple auto-responders can be done in Google Apps using the "Out of Office Autoreply" function (in Settings -> General on the individual account page).  This will however require a dedicated account.  You can do more complex things in this respect using the "Canned Responses" addon, which can be enabled from labs.  This has support for sending a canned response in response to a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite a wait for it to come out of Beta but just the other day Opera announced this: [MyOpera](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/10/opera_mail_beta/)

One for the future possibly if not now.

I really like (and use) the Gmail interface but in terms of reliability and functionality FastMail are a very close second: [FastMail](http://www.fastmail.fm/)

They are so long-established that their feature set is truly excellent and surpasses Gmail's offerings in several places. Also it's affordable even for advanced accounts (no I don't work for them!).